# "border-collapse:collapse" Parent table affects "border-spacing: 7px" child table in IE but not in Chrome, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have parent table `<table class="{style.removeBorderTable}" >`, the child table `<table class="{style.flexTable}">`

```
.flexTable { 
  border-spacing: 7px;
}

.removeBorderTable {
   border-collapse:collapse
}
```

In IE, it does not have border-space, look like this:
[image]

In Chrome, it has boprder-space, look like this
[image]

**SO, How to fix it?** The real code is very complicated, but when I removed `.removeBorderTable` then the table look the same in IE & in Chrome (ie, there is `border-spacing` in IE).

Comment: What is this syntax? `{style.removeBorderTable}` Some templating engine?

Comment: gwt syntax, it is the same as class="removeBorderTable" in normal html

Comment: You should post a minimal complete example (HTML and CSS) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by differences in browser style sheets (default rendering rules) between browsers. To fix it, set [`border-collapse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders) explicitly on the inner table. Since you apparently want the separate borders model, as otherwise setting border spacing would be meaningless, add

```
.flexTable { border-collapse: separate }
```

The browser default style sheet in Chrome (and in Firefox) contains the rule

```
table { border-collapse: separate }
```

as you can check in Developer Tools. This browser style sheet rule is an accordance with the suggested default [rendering rules for tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables) in HTML5. However, IE does not have such a rule. This is not a bug but a feature; default rendering rules are just suggested or expected; besides, HTML5 is still a draft (though being made official soon).

Thus, in IE, the inner table inherits `border-collapse` value from the outer table. This causes collapsed border model, where `border-spacing` is ignored. So you need to prevent that inheritance by using an explicit setting.

(The issue does not manifest itself unless tables are nested. In a simple table, in the absence of `border-collapse` setting, IE applies the *initial* value `separate`, as defined in CSS specifications.)